# ¿Cómo pasar una foto a otro layout?

Tags: android, layout, cámara

Lo que quiero es que al momento de tomar una foto se me muestre en un `imgview` pero de otra `layout`, lo que tengo actualmente es que presiono el `botton` de la cámara me pide permiso para tomar la foto después acepto esa foto y me la muestra en un `imgview` del la misma `layout`. Lo que quiero hacer es que una vez tomada la foto y ya haberle dado aceptar a la foto me mande directamente a otro `layout` con la foto mostrada en una `imgview`.

```
 private void showOptions() {
    final CharSequence[] option = {"Tomar foto", "Cancelar"};
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Elige una opción");
    builder.setItems(option, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(option[which] == "Tomar foto"){
                openCamera();
            }else if(option[which] == "Elegir de galeria"){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona app de imagen"), SELECT_PICTURE);
            }else {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
```

---

```
  private void openCamera() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), MEDIA_DIRECTORY);
    boolean isDirectoryCreated = file.exists();

    if(!isDirectoryCreated)
        isDirectoryCreated = file.mkdirs();

    if(isDirectoryCreated){
        Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        String imageName = timestamp.toString() + ".jpg";

        mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + MEDIA_DIRECTORY
                + File.separator + imageName;

        File newFile = new File(mPath);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(newFile));
        startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_CODE);
    }
}
```

Lo puse en un `imgview`:

```
mSetImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.set_picture);
```

Comment: Hola, podrias mostrar tu código? Que has intentado? Como lo has hecho? Pasate por el [tour] y [ask]

Comment: Si sólo quieres enviar una imagen (o cualquier objeto) de una Actividad a otra lo puedes hacer a través de un Intent, con recuperarlo casteándolo debería valer, pero como dice Antoni Alda deberías hacer mejor la pregunta, no está clara

Comment: Es nevesario agregar tu código...

Answer (score 0):

Yo hice algo similar, en el botón para hacer la foto:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
           startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
```

Después tienes que recoger el resultado en el metodo `onActivityResult` de tu `Activity`, ya es un Bitmap que puedes cargar en el `ImageView`:

```
 if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            last_picture = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.taidImageEdit)).setImageBitmap(last_picture); 
}
```